# how to pass data from tableviewcell to other xib?

Tags: core-data, xib

I am retrieving my data from core data now I want to update it.
I'm passing data in NSManagedObject, but how do I take it to other xib on cell tap where I will update that data?

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You simply pass the object in `prepareForSegue:`

```
DetailViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
controller.detailObject = cellManagedObject;
```

If you do not know how `prepareForSegue` works, you really should first read up on it rather than asking on this forum: [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html).

Comment: Here is the Solution :-

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Detail_View* detailViewController = [[Detail_View alloc] init];
    detailViewController.data = record;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

}

Comment: That's exactly the above solution, just with segues. (It is recommended by Apple to use segues rather than creating the controllers in code.) Your line `detailViewController.data = record;` is the same exact concept as my second line. --> you should accept the answer.

Comment: Dude I have mentioned there without "Seque".
But thank you for your reply .

Comment: Dude, 1. No you have not mentioned that. 2. It is immaterial to the solution if a segue is used or not.